# How do i fix this: Invalid JSON error message from Binance

Tags: json, amazon-cloudfront, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

I have been running a python script on an Amazon EC2 instance. It runs fine for a while and then I get this error:

```
Invalid JSON error message from Binance:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>503 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
This distribution exceeded the limit on requests per second.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: uQnEmv-kXx0j2v3WdxnbrkBlJDdI33fduqBNYhNoIVfv10G1_LZS1Q==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS> 
</BODY></HTML>
```

I am requesting the data every 1 minute.

I can't find any information about this error.

Comment: Are you scraping data from the Binance website? They are possibly restricting the number of requests to prevent this type of behaviour.

Comment: No, i'm using the API

Comment: I wonder why the error message mentions CloudFront? I presume that you are pointing at the Binance API endpoint, which suggests that they must be using CloudFront in front of the API endpoint (which is unusual).

Comment: Yes, no clue why the CloudFront Error; maybe the error is from Amazon? anyways i handle the error using the re-try system

Comment: I got the same issue as well. Don't pretty sure because I'm using python-binance lib, and by right, it should invoke Binance API instead of web (cloudfront). Not sure why do we get the CF error.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, do you have any updates?